# Is there a way to align the first node at the top instead of at the middle?

Tags: orgchart

I am using BalkanGraph plugin and I'm trying to align the first parent node of the orgchart to the top of the svg instead of the center of it.

I tried to set a negative "margin-top" and increases the height of the whole svg, but then the click goes with it, and it doesn't work well.

My only css is this:

```
#tree {
    width: 100%;
    height: 630px;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

and the things I am using in Orgchart are these:

```
var chart = new OrgChart(document.getElementById("tree"), {
    mouseScroolBehaviour: BALKANGraph.action.zoom,
    nodeMouseClickBehaviour: BALKANGraph.action.none,
    scaleInitial: BALKANGraph.match.boundary,

    collapse: {
        level: 2,
        allChildren: true
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Set **align** option to **BALKANGraph.ORIENTATION**

```
   var chart = new OrgChart(document.getElementById("tree"), {
            align: BALKANGraph.ORIENTATION,
            ...
   });
```

Comment: Just tried this, sorry for the waiting. Didn't work, it's still centralized. I am not setting any orientation, so the default is top, right? tried setting it too, but it didn't change :/.
Any others ideas?

Comment: Remove scaleInitial: BALKANGraph.match.boundary from the settings